# How to set the Type of a function in Typescript, when passing that into another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, typescript

Here is my function:

```
const payout = (asset: ILPAsset, type: string)
    => type === 'daily' ? asset.lastPayout : asset.historical;
```

And where I'm using it:

```
@bind
private mapDailyAssets(payoutType: string, payout: payoutFunc, assets: ILPAsset[], currency: string) {
  return assets.map((asset) => (
    <div className={b('table-row')()} key={asset.symbol}>
      <div>{asset.symbol}</div>
      <div className={b('asset-value')()}>{formatMoney(payout(asset, payoutType), currency)}</div>
    </div>
  ));
}
```

I'm getting errors when trying to set an `interface` for type `payoutFunc`:

```
interface payoutFunc: (asset: ILPAsset, type: string) => string;
```

But also getting this error:

> invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for declaring a function signature interface is not quite right. It should look like this:

```
interface payoutFunc { 
  (asset: ILPAsset, type: string): string;
}
```

Or you could use a [type alias](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases):

```
type payoutFunc = (asset: ILPAsset, type: string) => string;
```

In either case you can use this type as a prop somewhere else:

```
interface MyProps {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  payout: payoutFunc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed, other questions on stack just covered the function itself, wasn't looking for the Typescript function type syntax.